# How can i call a function function present in another Component on headerRight Press

Tags: react-native

Onpress headerRight button i want to call a function present in another component. But the problem is how can i do that. plz help me guys. Thanks in Advance.

```
<Stack.Screen
    name="Filter Meals"
    component={FilterScreen}
    options={{
        headerLeft:()=><View style={{paddingLeft:10,}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
        <HeaderButton title="Menu" name="menu" type="material"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>,
        headerRight:()=><View style={{paddingLeft:10,}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{}}>
        <HeaderButton title="Save" name="save" type="material"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>,
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontFamily:"OpenSans-Bold"
        }
      }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different options for doing that , **provided that** your **another component** (the component you want doing operation after called the function ) was **mounted** , you can use following instructions:

```
    const [isAction , setIsAction] = React.useState(false);

    const _toggleMyAction = ()=> {
      return setIsAction(!isAction);
    };

    <Stack.Screen
    name="Filter Meals"
    component={FilterScreen}
    options={{
        headerLeft:()=><View style={{paddingLeft:10,}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>navigation.toggleDrawer()}>
        <HeaderButton title="Menu" name="menu" type="material"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>,
        headerRight:()=><View style={{paddingLeft:10,}}>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={_toggleMyAction}>
        <HeaderButton title="Save" name="save" type="material"/>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>,
        headerTitleStyle:{
            fontFamily:"OpenSans-Bold"
        }
      }}
```

If the other component is accessible for this component (example it's one of the child components) you can give isAction and _toggleMyAction as props, but if it's not relation to each other you must set isAction in the store and _toggleMyAction in the reducer (you can use React Context or Redux or etc) and have access that.

Then in the component that you want execute operation after clicked on the **right button**:

```
...
...

React.useEffect(()=>{
   if (isAction){
     //doing my operation

    //and if be need after operation toggle the isAction here or your needed place
   };

} , [isAction]);

...
...
```

Comment: Ty so much for the answer

Comment: you're welcome,i hope it's has been helpful

Comment: I'found another short way to implement that using setOptions